# Jquery selector.each: how to iterate through list x at a time?

Tags: jquery

so I have the following HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="id id1-1">id1-1</li>
  <li class="id id1-2">id1-2</li>
  <li class="id id1-3">id1-3</li>
  <li class="id id2-1">id2-1</li>
  <li class="id id2-2">id2-2</li>
  <li class="id id2-3">id2-3</li>
  <li class="id id3-1">id3-1</li>
  <li class="id id3-2">id3-2</li>
  <li class="id id3-3">id3-3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to iterate/process the items 3 at a time.

something like: (not working!)

```
$(".id").each(function(index){
    $(this).hide() //processes idx-1
    index=index+1; //move to idx-2

    $(this).hide() //processes idx-2
    index=index+1; //move to idx-3

    $(this).hide() //processes idx-3. on next iteration. each "pointer" is at 4th item.
});
```

Any ideas how it can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `for` loop

```js
$(function() {
  var li = $(".id");

  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i += 2) {
    console.log("================= " + i);
    console.log($(li[i]).text());
    console.log($(li[i + 1]).text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="id id1-1">id1-1</li>
  <li class="id id1-2">id1-2</li>
  <li class="id id1-3">id1-3</li>
  <li class="id id2-1">id2-1</li>
  <li class="id id2-2">id2-2</li>
  <li class="id id2-3">id2-3</li>
  <li class="id id3-1">id3-1</li>
  <li class="id id3-2">id3-2</li>
  <li class="id id3-3">id3-3</li>
</ul>
```